# Executing functions inside string

Tags: php

Everyone knows in PHP you can do this:

```
$m = "my string is {$string}";
```

But is taht possibile with function too? Like:

```
$m = "my string is {getStringValue()}";
```

Comment: string is a string and function is a function. why do you want to put one into another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string expansion in `{$..}` goes a bit beyond just being able to execute functions. I for example used gettext with that. But you can also use tricks like that:

```
$html = "htmlentities";    // any callback function
// or just: $html = function($s){ return $s; }

print "even allows expressions {$html(2+3*5+rand(2,17))} here";
```

That's possible because PHP allows any ***variable* expression** there in order to support the simple object notation case:

```
print "this isn't just a {$obj->prop} string variable";
```

And for example I'm utilizing an object which implements ArrayAccess, where even this is a method invocation:

```
print "Makes some things {$_GET->ascii->html['input']} simpler";
```

We had a few such topics on SO, but for the life of me I can't find a good reference ...

Comment: this just shows how powerful PHP is, and especially how much important is the `$` mark for var. Contrarily at the comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362274/why-javascript-permits-for-name-of-functions/5362308#5362308)

Comment: can you explain a bit more how do you avchive that object form `$_GET` ? `$_GET->ascii` ?

Comment: That's a input filter object I use. It's quite cool, but you have to use it througout the application then. It allows `$_GET->safe["input"]` and `$_GET["raw"]` access alike, which makes it quite useful to secure legacy apps. http://sourceforge.net/p/php7framework/svn/60/tree/trunk/php7/input.php?force=True - but it's not finished yet.

Comment: It still uses filter_var behind the scenes. But e.g. filter_vars FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL fails on a few valid email addresses. Otherwise, filter_var is ok however. I just dislike it because it's more cumbersome to use and provides too few practical filters.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible (and it wouldn't be very readable too, especially if the function had parameters).

You could use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
 $m = sprintf("my string is %s", getStringValue());
```

Comment: I don't quitly agree. I think it's more readable this: `"string {func()} other string"` than `"string ".func()." other string"`

Comment: Of course, that's subjective, but I think it's easy to make mistakes like that. In my experience, sprintf is the most readable and reusable solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Only variable names are expanded
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: The manual lies. :} It's actually not just variable names, but variable *expressions* which get expanded.

Answer (score 0):

With concatenation, If I understand well what you're trying to do:

```
$m = "my string is {".getStringValue()."}";
```